# Remove price from category page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-enterprise-2

In magento2 - I want to remove price from category page ( product listing ) in magento enterprise version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**

```
<?php  //echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
```

comment this line...

Note : if you not find file above path than copy from

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

to

`app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Comment: thanks. it's working. but is there any way to do same from layout.xml file?

Comment: cannot be via layout because of `getProductPrice($_product)` is defined via Php code

Comment: Okay. thanks @AmitBera for information.

Answer (score 1):

We use a different solution with applying a CSS-style:

```
div.products.wrapper.grid.products-grid div.price-box.price-final_price, /*pricing in categories*/
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

We use this way to avoid problems with the updated `list.phtml` file by further Magento updates and in our case hiding price is only a "nice to have" but not business-critical.